# How to get File Created Date and Modified Date

Tags: c#, file, io, last-modified, datecreated

I have an .NET EXE file .
I want to find the file created date and modified date in C# application. Can do it through reflection or with IO stream?

Comment: Have a look at the `File` class, should't be that hard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: Google gets a lot of result if you searched it first.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You could use below code:

```
DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt");
```

Comment: if i want to know the same thing with file bytes. how could it be?

Comment: Note--if it comes back with a minimum date it's probably because the file doesn't exist/invalid path, etc.  (It doesn't throw an exception)

Answer (score 50):

You can do that using [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("path");
var created = fi.CreationTime;
var lastmodified = fi.LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: Per the link, "If you are performing multiple operations on the same file, it can be more efficient to use FileInfo instance methods instead of the corresponding static methods of the File class, because a security check will not always be necessary."

Answer (score 9):

[`File.GetLastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) to Get last modified

[`File.CreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get Created time

Answer (score 7):

Use :

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo('FilePath');
var fFirstTime = fInfo.CreationTime;
var fLastTime = fInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: These things don't stand alone. The are part of a class. Which class?

Comment: The SystemIO class

Answer (score 6):

[File.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) Method

> Returns the date and time the specified file or directory was last written to.

```
string path = @"c:\Temp\MyTest.txt";
DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
```

For create time [File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) Method

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt");
Console.WriteLine("file created: " + fileCreatedDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to see the last modified date of a file.

```
DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
```

And this code to see the creation time.

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt");
```

Comment: just remember, there is a bug going back to the 90s in NTFS - windows OS gui - that mixes the created date with the modified date (ever wonder why they never fixed it?)