# In pdf hyperlink modify date of pdf at runtime using C# .net

Tags: c#, date, pdf, adobe, aspose

One pdf is generated and I am adding link of website in some text of pdf using aspose and below code,

```
var link = new Aspose.Pdf.Annotations.LinkAnnotation(document.Pages[t.p], userSignRect)
{
    Action = new Aspose.Pdf.Annotations.GoToURIAction(requestHostAddress.Replace("http://", "https://") + "/document-details/" + documentId)
};
```

Now I want to append pdf's modified date run time in hyperlink.

Example : https://document-details/documentId/ ModifiedDateofPdfRuntime

Please help me/guide me how to do that.

**Edit:** I do not want current modified date.
**Usecase :** We have generated pdf and given to user with our basic hyperlink url in pdf.(which is a happy scenario)

But if someone is altering my pdf then i won't know and pdf's url will still route to my website.

To overcome same i want to append PDF's modified date object in url which will fetch pdf info and get date.

something like this, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
   DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt");
   DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt");
```

and then you can add checks to check if file is modified or not.
code is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243336/how-to-get-file-created-date-and-modified-date).

Comment: No I don't need today's date. I want to get pdf's Modified date from pdf object so if it is modified in future i would know that it is modified.

Comment: I have edited my answer.Have a look again and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Action = new Aspose.Pdf.Annotations.GoToURIAction(requestHostAddress
     .Replace("http://", "https://") + "/document-details/" + documentId + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ModDate property from [PdfFileInfo](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf.facades/pdffileinfo) class:

```
using Aspose.Pdf.Facades;

//...

var fileInfo = new PdfFileInfo(dataDir + "GetFileInfo.pdf");
var modificationDate = fileInfo.ModDate;
```

Hope it helps. Otherwise, feel free to ask me.

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks, But this will give me current modified date of pdf. What i want is pdf is generated and some has altered pdf or modified it. Now when they will click on pdf URL, it comes on my website. which i do not want. So I want to get current modified pdf date appended in url runtime to check.