# Add Date Filter in file upload while click on file upload button in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dates from and until and I want to add the filter on the file upload button:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" style="background-color: #d19629;"
accept=".csv" />
```

If I click on that `FileUpload` button show only those files that are  in my date range, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can't do that. What you can do is that check file creation date(or modification date) on [`FileUpload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile) click event:

```
 System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + FileUpload1.FileName);
 if(fileInfo.CreationTime > ... &&   fileInfo.CreationTime < ...) //check document creation date
 {
    //..
 }
 else
 {
   //the file is not in date range
 
 }
```

See also: [How to get File Created Date and Modified Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243336/how-to-get-file-created-date-and-modified-date)